# Why does Dr. Grace Augustine argue with Parker Selfridge about Jake Sully?

Tags: avatar

Why does Dr. Grace Augustine argue with Parker Selfridge about Jake Sully being assigned to her *after* Sully has already landed on Pandora?

Was this not decided 5 years ago before he left to go to Pandora? Why is she only objecting now?

Answer (score 3):

I think we can be reasonably sure that Grace wasn't told about Jake subbing in for his (dead) brother until the Venture Star arrived at Pandora, based on her extreme reaction and given the fabulous cost of sending FTL communications.

> There is a drawback, however, in that you can only send three bits of information per hour and it is extremely costly at $7,500 per bit
>
> <sub><sup>[Superluminal Communications](https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Superluminal_Communications)</sup></sub>

Transmitting a signal to explain that "*T.Sully=ded, sendg J.Sully insted. No useful skils. Tel G.Augstn we=soz*" would cost half a million dollars and achieve nothing.